# Date validation getting issue, "End date value should be minor than today" using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I stuck with date validation, here requirement is end date should be less than today's date(user will enter end date.)

I wrote the following code, if I gave smaller and bigger than todays date also showing error alert. Could any one help me please.

```
var endDate = "03/02/2016 09:53:51";
var endDateTime = endDate.split(/\/|-|\s|:/);

var curdate = new Date();
var todaysDt = curdate.getDate()+ "-" + (curdate.getMonth()+1) + "-" + curdate.getFullYear() + " " +curdate.getHours() + ":" + curdate.getMinutes() + ":" + curdate.getSeconds();

if(endDateTime < todaysDt){
    alert("End date should be minor than today");   
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5qkt8e06/102/)

Comment: Thanks, but I need HH:MM:SS as well,is there any solution for this

Comment: What do you mean, you need HH:MM:SS? Can you describe in words if you want the *date* being before *today*, or you want *date+time* be before *now*? I.e. is "one hour ago today" okay or not?

Comment: Here, end date format is dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS, I would like to compare with current dateTime(dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss)

Comment: Then, `new Date(endDate) < new Date()` does exactly that. Don't compare strings, compare timestamps (and JavaScript `Date` is actually datetime).

Comment: Thanks, it is working the date format like dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss format, im getting date like dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss, it gives invalid date, is there any solution please

Comment: Please ask questions that are actually relevant to your need. If you are getting dates with dashes, why does your question's `endDate` use slashes? Also relevant - where are you getting this dashed date? If possible, make it return an ISO date, since other date formats may be ambiguous between dd/mm and mm/dd. (Specifically, `"22-04-2016 10:12:14"` is invalid; `"04-22-2016 10:12:14"` is parseable.)